# why NetBeans is not displaying warning in regards to variable length argument

Tags: java, netbeans, annotations

I'm currently learning Java @SafeVarargs. I have created an method that accept different length of int array as argument and invoked the method. However, NetBeans did not display any warning in regards to unsafe use of variable length argument. Why is it not displaying the warning? Could someone please tell me?

```
static void safeVarargsMethod(int... a){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DeclaringAnAnnotationType.safeVarargsMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code ([taken from the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html)) demonstrates the problem in NetBeans 8.0.2 (as well as Eclipse Mars.2):

```
static void m(List<String>... stringLists) {
  Object[] array = stringLists;
  List<Integer> tmpList = Arrays.asList(42);
  array[0] = tmpList; // Semantically invalid, but compiles without warnings
  String s = stringLists[0].get(0); // Oh no, ClassCastException at runtime!
}
```

[image]

I think the problem is that your example doesn't demonstrate the problem in the first place.

Comment: Could you please upload a full screen shot instead of a partial screen shot? Thank you very much for your help!